# Intermittently Delay in Receiving Email Messages by Gmail Api

Tags: delay, gmail-api

I'm facing intermittently delay with polling email messages via Gmail API from GSuite user's inbox. Those calls origin from automatic jobs and use multiple G-Suite users to disperse the work and avoid reaching Quota limits.
However, there are still delay of at least 3 minutes in reading the email. Investigating message email headers showed neither errors (429) or delay time, nor quota limits are being reached.
I examined the push notification method and I'm limited to use it.

Are limit units calculated according to domain rather than per G-Suite user so I'm indeed reach quota?
What else can cause those delays?

Answer (score 0):

The Gmail API has usage limits per method and per user.

- [Email sending limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852) are calculated per user per day, not per domain.
- Limit units are calculated from all requests made from your application per day

You can check your [quota in the Cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/gmail.googleapis.com/quotas), choosing your project and API (in this case Gmail).

[image]

Comment: Hi Ziganotschka, I checked all those quotas and nothing have reached. However I still experience delays.

Comment: It's normal that emails take some time to arrive e.g. due to network traffic, spam filters propagation etc.  3 minutes is not that long and unfortunately there is not much you can do about it.

Comment: I see, do you have another recommendations? Do you know if https://mailtrap.io has good performance?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I could clearly see the email inside the 'Sent' folder but the recipient had not got any email, so I knew the limits for using the API had not been crossed. It was spam protection taking a ton of time to figure out if the sent email was spam or not. The most common case would be if your emails are all similar with a link in them. I removed the hyperlink in my template email notification and it started working again without any delay.